# How can I hide a Select element from view, but still have it open the dropdown options when another element is clicked?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My site will have a select element to select a color.  I'd rather have a nice button that says "Pick a Color" and when you click it, it opens the dropdown.

So my thought is to have a button DIV with the Select element inside it, and I position the Select element ON TOP of the button, but make it's opacity 0 so you can't see it.  Then when you click the button, the dropdown opens up as normal...

```
<div class='color-button'>Pick a Color
<select name='color' id='colorpicker' class='hide-color-select'>
//bunch of color options here
</select>
</div>

div.color-button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #eeeeee;
    }

.hide-cat-select {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0.01;
    }
```

NOTE:  It actually doesn't let you click to open the Select element when opacity is set to 0, but it does as long as it's not zero. So 0.01 opacity still "hides" it but allows clicking.

Thoughts on this? It feels pretty hacky, so if someone has suggestions on a better/more efficient way to handle this, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: In fact, that select has not the opacity:0 just because you click on a button. This is visible even you set opacity:0. The question is what you need to do? This is just a basic select, in your example.

Comment: I agree with @MadalinaTaina, the behavior you are looking for is the one of a simple `select`. As an alternative, you can use `input` type `color` but that still lacks some browser support.

Comment: There are a lot of alternatives, like @Ricky_Ruiz said, the dropdown can be a div too, but it seems you don't have a real question here.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I must not have explained it well.  See Niran's example below.  In essence, I want to hide the actual select element from view.  So in his example, I'd like to only see "Pick a Color" on the screen. And if you clicked that text, it would open the dropdown options.   So I guess my question is "How can I hide the actual select element from view, but still have it open when something else is clicked?"

Comment: Just take a look into libraries like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) and [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Answer (score 1):

```html
        <div class='color-button'>Pick a Color
            <select name='color' id='colorpicker' class='hide-color-select'>
                <option value="red">red</option>
                <option value="green">green</option>
                <option value="blue">blue</option>
                <option value="black">black</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

select drop down opotion use like this